# jQuery - mouseover/mouseout with multiple divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

I have a hidden div nested inside a larger div, and set it up so when you mouseover the larger div, the hidden div slides down. On mouseout, the div slides back. The problem is, when the mouse goes over the smaller div, it tries to slide it back up because the mouseout event was triggered. How can I prevent the div from hiding again until the mouse is over neither div?

html:

```
<div id="topbarVis" class="col1 spanall height1 wrapper">
    <div id="topbar"></div>
</div>
```

(the extra classes are part of a modular css system and define the width and height, among other things, of #topbarVis

css:

```
#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

js:

```
// On Mouseover -> Show
$("#topbarVis").mouseover(function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:0}, 300);
});
// On Mouseout -> Hide
$("#topbarVis").mouseout(function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:-25}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mouseenter/mouseleave` instead:

```
$("#topbarVis").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:0}, 300);
})
 .mouseleave(function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:-25}, 300);
});
```

...or just use the [`hover()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method  which is a shortcut for `mouseenter/mouseleave`:

```
$("#topbarVis").hover(function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:0}, 300);
},function(){
  $("#topbar").animate({marginTop:-25}, 300);
});
```

The reason is that the nature of `mouseover/mouseout` is such that it bubbles. So it will fire when any descendants of the element get the events. Whereas `mouseenter/mouseleave` don't bubble.

The only browser that *actually* supports the non-standard `mouseenter/mouseleave` events is IE, but jQuery replicates its behavior.

Comment: what is the difference here? I got the same behavior with `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`

Comment: @jAndy: You shouldn't get that behavior. The `mosueenter/mouseleave` should only fire for the element to which it is actually attached. Not its descendants.

Comment: @jAndy: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/P9jeN/). When you hover the outer square, the event fires. But not on the inner. [If you switch it](http://jsfiddle.net/P9jeN/2/) to mouseover/mouseout, it will fire on the inner as well.

Comment: @jAndy: Nope, just regular bubbling from descendant to the element that has the handler. It seems a little strange because when you hover the inner square, it first fires a `mouseout` because you're technically *leaving* the outer square. That is to say that you're leaving the portion of it that is not obscured by its descendant. The IE `mouseenter/mouseleave` system seems to make much more sense, but it isn't part of the spec. :o(

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on IE. Hope it helps.

```
$("#topbarVis").hover(function(){   $("#topbar").animate({height:"100%"}, 300); },function(){   $("#topbar").animate({height:"0%"}, 300); });
```

Using this as the CSS.

```
#topbar {   width: 100%;   height:0px;   background-color: #000; }
```